# how to grant permission for background location react native

Tags: react-native

I'm struggling to publish the app to google play because of that permission request.

I have provided location permission asks. but it has only 2 label options allow/reject.
as far as I see I need to put getBackgroundPermissionOptionLabel() with more options.
followed: https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#foreground

how do I do that on react native?

Comment: Have you saw [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid)?

Comment: yes, I did that, I just see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66362196/android-react-native-avoiding-background-location-access-not-declared-in-googl hope it works. it seems like google-play does problems with the background permission